# Missing parameters after processing a Facebook signed_request

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook, c#-4.0, facebook-c#-sdk

I'm using the following code to generate a facebook registration form:

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/registration.php?
         client_id=$MyClientID&
         redirect_uri=http://localhost/connect/account/RegisterFacebook&fields=name,birthday,gender,location,email"
         scrolling="auto"
         frameborder="no"
         style="border: none" 
         allowtransparency="true" 
         width="100%" 
         height="330">
```

According to their documentation (and their test site, where my registration information appears to post correctly), I should have access to the register's name, birthday, gender, location, and email - to be used in my local registration process. I get all of the other parameters (i.e. oauth_toke, user_id, algorithm, expires, etc), but I don't get the "registration" parameters (appear to be nested). I downloaded the latest API, but those variables do not appear available.

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Is this in a live implementation? Perhaps the user's are not allowing to share that data when connecting to app?

Comment: Jason - I'm testing with my own account. All the data is populated when I click register (and the facebook test page shows it is available), but when I point to my own page, it appears only a small portion of the information is available from the method that decodes the signed_request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, we do not support this scenario. We are going to have a fix in sometime in the next few days to allow the registration plugin to work with the Facebook C# SDK. It will be included with version 5.0.2.

Comment: Thanks Nathan. You guys are doing great work with the asp.net MVC SDK. It's a blessing to people like me who do some programming on the side. Thanks for your contributions and your answers on Stackoverflow.

Comment: This is supported from v5.0.2. There is also a new sample called CSASPNETWebsiteRegistrationForm demonstrating how to use it.

Comment: Prabir, can you point me to where the CSASPNETWebsiteRegistrationForm sample is located? Thanks!